# Azure devops - cannot force push branch with maximal permissions

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to force push my changes to a branch with policies and I get an error even though I have Allow on all permissions in Azure Devops repositories.

[image]

[image]

Am I not getting something here ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

the problem was that there can be policies on multiple levels.

Repos -> branches -> 3 dots on a branch -> Branch security

[image]

Branch policy had different policies then repository

[image]

After chaning it there I was able to force push my changes.

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards

Comment: You changed it where exactly?

Comment: Repos -> branches -> 3 dots on a branch -> Branch security. There is a description here as well https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-repos-bypass-branch-policies/